# When I enterd 10 as input the output is 10 and 5. Why value Doesn't change in main()? and if I remove static int in static block than output is 10

Tags: java, static

When I enter 10 as input the output is 10 and 5. Why doesn't value change in `main()`? And if I remove `static int` in static block than output is 10 and 10.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
    
public class Demo5 {
    static int i=5;
    static {
        Scanner p=new Scanner(System.in);
        int i=p.nextInt();
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    public static void main(String[] s)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `int i` inside the static initializer block is a local variable that shadows (i.e. hides) the `static int i` field in `Demo5`.

In other words: with the code like this the `i` in the two `System.out.println(i)` lines refers to two different things. One local variable and one static field, both named `i`.

And the moral of the story: don't name your local variables the same as your fields, or you will get confusion like that. The compiler can handle it just fine, but for humans it gets weird.